# Loading Ajax Data Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a bunch of jQuery functions which gets JSON data from a MySQL database and displays it on certain pages within my application.

i have about 15 of these functions that look similar to the below and i would like to tidy them up and convert them to one major function which returns data based on the variables passed to the function. IE getdata(subscriptions) would display the subscriptions.

My issue is i'm not sure how to pass the column names to the function from the ajax query and remove the value.column-name from the function.

Example function from application

```
function GetSubscriptions(){    
    $.ajax({
    url: 'jsondata.php', 
    type: 'POST',       
    dataType:'json',
    timeout:9000,                       
    success: function (response)                
    {           
      var trHTML = '';    
      $.each(response, function (key,value) {
         trHTML += 
            '<tr><td>' + value+ 
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_name + 
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_cycle +    
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_cost +     
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_retail +   
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_profit +   
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_margin + 
            '</td><td>' + value.subscription_markup +                               
            '</td></tr>';                   
      });
        $('#subscription-results').html(trHTML);
    },          
  });   
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated as i'm fairly new to jQuery

Comment: I need some clarity regarding your question. I didn't get your actual problem.

Comment: basically i have 15 functions all doing the same thing on different pages, i'm looking to condense those functions down to 1 and specifying which data to show

Comment: Do you want to control which columns should be returned from the database as JSON?

Comment: no this is done on the database end. i just need to display the columns returned from the database.

Comment: Just post the JSON response that you are getting from your ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this code:

```
function GetSubscriptions(){    
  $.ajax({
      url: 'jsondata.php', 
      type: 'POST',       
      dataType:'json',
      timeout:9000,                       
      success: function (response)                
      {               
          $('#subscription-results').html(parseColumns(response));
      },          
  });
}   
function parseColumns(columns) {
    var html = '';

    if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(columns) === '[object Array]') {
        $.each(columns, function(key, value) {
            html += parseColumn(value);
        })
    } else {
        html += parseColumn(columns);
    }

    function parseColumn(column) {
        var trHTML = '<tr><td>' + column + '</td>';

        for (var key in column) {
           trHTML += '<td>' + column[key] + '</td>'
        }
        trHTML += '</tr>';

        return trHTML;
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: i get unexpected ) when running this code on the following line $.each(columns, function(key, value)) {

Comment: sorry, there is  a extra ) after the `function(key, value))`,I edit it

Comment: this is perfect, however some of the columns have a link on the end that link to an edit or delete modal. is there a way to implement this as well for certain colums

Comment: actually in the first function i could just add the code there before sending the html back to the page.

Comment: for certain columns you can add a if condition in the for loop of  the `parseColumn` function,just like:`for(var key in column){if(key ==='link'){trHTML+='<td><span onclick="" class="edit">'+column[key]+'</span></td>}else{trHTML+='<td>'+column[key]+'</td>';}}`